# How to access field values from an entity reference field in a custom module?

Tags: commerce, entities

I'm making a custom payment module for Commerce that references a Credit Card entity. I have the entity reference form field in there and working but I cannot pass on the selected Credit Card entity to the "message" field. If I could just print whatever the title of the entity reference they select, that would work, or if I could access one of the 5 fields in the entity itself, that would be ideal.

Here is my module: http://pastebin.com/373WDAzA and this is the error message I get:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1559 of C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\bootstrap.inc).

Answer (score 0):

```
$form['card_on_file' ] = array(
  '#type' => 'entityreference',
  '#title' => t ('Credit Card'),
  '#era_entity_type' => 'node', // Mandatory 
  '#era_bundles' => array(credit_card ), // Optional (Any bundle by default).
  '#era_cardinality' => 5, // Optional (1 By default).
  '#required' => TRUE,
) ;
```

the warning corresponds to this replace this code:

```
'#era_bundles' => array(credit_card ), // Optional (Any bundle by default).
```

with

```
'#era_bundles' => array('credit_card'),
```

Link: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7

```
$ids = array();
```

get `$ids` from `$form_state['values']` of submit handler function.

use `entity_load('credit_card', $ids);`

Comment: Hi harshal, I get this error when I remove the array () from the #era_bundles -> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in entityreference_autocomplete_validate_entityreference()

Comment: check the edited answer

Comment: I get the same error with the edit. Just to be clear, all I've done is add '' around credit_card. I have not changed anything else in the module.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to the #drupal-support IRC room. I did a `dpm($pane_values)` and saw that it was retrieving what I wanted, the Entity Label. I just changed the code so that it's

```
$pane_values['card_on_file'][0]['entity_label']
```

and presto!